# Extjs failing store.getRootNode().findChild('idelement', record.data.idelement, true) after the first success load

Tags: extjs

I'm building a tree on demand, I mean, if I double click a node then it fetches data from an api rest and then populates the node.

This is what I'm doing:

```
itemdblclick: function (item, record, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('mystore');
    var newStore = Ext.create('mycomponent.mystore', {
        autoDestroy: true
    });
    var node = store.getRootNode().findChild('idelement', record.data.idelement, true);
    var parentid = record.data.idelement;

    var that = this;

    newStore.proxy.extraParams = {
        sort: 'clave',
        'filter[active]': true,
        'filter[idparent]' = parentid
    };

    newStore.load({
        callback: function(items) {
            for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
                var item = items[i].data;
                var child = {
                    idparent = parentid,
                    ...
                };
                node.appendChild(child, true);
            }
            node.expand();
        }
    });
}
```

The first call returns the data properly and inserts it into the node. From there on, every double click producess and error telling me this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Is there any way to solve this? How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using reference param in asynchronous callback method (`load`).
You should assign node parameter inside and check if still node exists.

```
itemdblclick: function (item, record, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('mystore');
    var newStore = Ext.create('mycomponent.mystore', {
        autoDestroy: true
    });
    var parentid = record.data.idelement;

    var that = this;

    newStore.proxy.extraParams = {
        sort: 'clave',
        'filter[active]': true,
        'filter[idparent]' = parentid
    };

    newStore.load({
        callback: function(items) {
            var node = store.getRootNode().findChild('idelement', parentid, true);
            if (node) {
                for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var item = items[i].data;
                    var child = {
                        idparent = parentid,
                        ...
                    };
                    node.appendChild(child, true);
                }
                node.expand();
            }
        }
    });
}
```